# Display a message only if there are no errors

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I currently have a batch script which uses powershell to unzip a file.

```
powershell Expand-Archive C:\File1\File22.zip -DestinationPath C:\File1\File2\
```

If there are no errors with extracting the zip file, I would like to run the following:

```
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo WScript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "Updating! Please wait... " ,10 ,"Update", 0)) >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs
cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
if %errorlevel%==1 (
  echo You Clicked OK
) else (
  echo The Message timed out.
)
del %tmp%\tmp.vbs
```

How can I add an `if` `else` statement to my code?

Comment: After the command `powershell…` add `if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (` then the code you wanna run and then `)`. It should work.

Comment: I'd suggest using `-ErrorAction Stop` to your `Expand-Archive` operation so it stops trying to expand and also closes the script with a non-zero error level

Comment: I would also add, that I see no need to write a batch script for `cmd.exe` to run a `powershell.exe` command, that writes, runs then deletes a `cscript.exe` script. Powershell has the ability to output dialog boxes so at the very least you should utilise it, and preferably do all of it directly in `powershell.exe`. _Oh and BTW, can you please delete [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55065301)?_

Comment: You are already checking the errorlevel of the Vbscript.  Did you think you could not do the same for Powershell?  Regardless of that, pick one scripting language to do all of this in.  Mixing three seems a bit too much.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to execute the powershell command first, then check to make sure it exited with error code 0 (a successful execution).

```
powershell Expand-Archive C:\File1\File22.zip -DestinationPath C:\File1\File2\
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
    echo WScript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "Updating! Please wait... " ,10 ,"Update", 0)) 
        >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs
    cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        echo You Clicked OK
    ) else (
        echo The Message timed out.
    )
del %tmp%\tmp.vbs
)
```

Comment: Good reply to the OP's question.  But it begs the question - wouldn't it be better if the OP just did *everything* in PS, rather than mixing .bat + .vbs + .ps1 together in an over-complicated solution?

Comment: Oh easily yes, however I am unfortunately not knowledgeable enough in powershell and this question is posted under the batch-file tag. But in short, yes.

Comment: You need to use delayed expansion for the second errorlevel check because it is inside a parentheses code block. Or, use `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 `.

Comment: Can you elaborate by what you mean by IF ERRORLEVEL 1?

Comment: Sure I can elaborate.  It is the very first syntax option in the help file for the `IF` command.  Open up a command prompt and type: `IF /?` to read about it.

Comment: What does IF ERRORLEVEL 1 actually check for? Is it just checking if it is equal to anything other than 0?

Comment: @Compo Then what is the difference between the new syntax and OP's syntax for that line?

Comment: Again, from the help file. **Specifies a true condition if the last program run returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number specified.**

Comment: You also have several other syntax problems with your code.  I am going to assume you never tested your code before you posted it as an answer.

Comment: You're `echo`ing strings within a parenthesised block, so you need to be sure that you're not prematurely closing that block.